# Explaining Deathwatt

Tags: science-based, biology, fauna

The Atomic Deathworm. An interesting concept, one I adapted. Living in sand is not likely for a worm, unless, of course, that sand is near or in water-plenty of worms live in wet sand. However, Deathwatt are still highly unusual creatures, because:

**1. Size:**  You know those big soda bottles you can get at the store? Imagine a worm that's about that wide and about that long. Yep, Deathwatt is a chunky lil' monster.

**2. Amphibiousness:** Deathwatt prefer living in water, but they can and will go on land for short periods to chase down prey. They aren't exactly fast on land, granted, but they can swim quite quickly and can also dig through wet sand to attack potential prey.

**3. Aggression:** Deathwatt tend to ram or bite creatures that come near them with their hardened mandibles, which they use to dig through sand. In other words, they are just as aggressive as the cryptid that inspired them. And, what's worse, is they can:

**4. Shock:** Surprise! Or not, depending on your familiarity with deathworms. Like the Atomic Deathworm, Deathwatt can generate and release electrical charges to zap food or foe, stunning or even killing like an electric eel.

**5. Acid:** Also like deathworms, Deathwatt possess acid, which they use to soften up prey and aid in digestion, mostly to aid in defense against predators on land. They can shoot this acid, which is strong enough to eat through leather in seconds, up to 3 yards, enough of it to eat a tennis-ball-sized crater in the victim. This same acid diffuses quickly underwater, making it useless except as a repellent to discourage attacks.

**5. Bite:** Before, I mentioned Deathwatt has mandibles, used for digging. Well, these mandibles are also capable of cutting and crushing, like a bobbit worm's. Between their shock and their bite, Deathwatt are pretty much apex predators.

My question is: **Is a Creature With These Traits Feasible?**

Comment: I know a good defense is a good offense and a good offense is a good offense, but isn't piling up 3+ kind of attacks with 2 very specific (electric+acid) kinda bit much :p? Even if we took a gaming approach, creatures that don't use magic are generally themed around one or two themes/elements max, especially for small ones. It's for the ease of understanding, if you see :).

Comment: @Tortliena: ah, but it's very simple. We have two elements: Poison and Electric. The third attack is a neutral, non-elemental attack that deals normal damage. Very necessary when its elemental attacks won't work.

Comment: I've rolled back your recent edit. Don't edit posts to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @sphennings: okay, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Not in any world grounded in real world physics.

The acid you've described is pretty infeasible. While it is possible for acid to eat through leather, it doesn't do it in a matter of seconds. Acids dissolve things on a much slower time scale than you're looking for. If you pay attention to the videos of powerful acids eating through things you'll note that they often come back after an hour or more to show the results.

Comment: Oof, time to scale that back or go to the magic board then. Thanks for your input!

Comment: especially if you need it to diffuse unnaturally quickly in water, since that is what flesh basically is.